# Problems in saving large data in Magento Order Model

Tags: php, magento

We have a Magento extension where we get lot of information from an ERP system and save in Magento. We are currently facing an issue while saving order information.

Scenario as follows,

1. We pick 25 pending orders from Magento.
2. We divide it into batch of 10 and call an API that responds with the order related information. The information includes shipment, invoice and tracking number.
3. During first iteration, we receive the information for the first batch of 10 orders. Once we do, we do a traditional Magento model save() operation.
4. When we try to send the next batch of 10 orders, the weird issue occurs.
5. Since the save of the first 10 orders in Magento is not complete yet, it fails to handle the next 10 orders.

Question is, is there a wait or some other similar kind of operation where I can make the process to wait till the save of first 10 orders is complete? Searched enough on internet and stackoverflow but in vain.

P.S: There is no exception or error being thrown at all. Just the actual process doesn't get complete.

P.P.S: It works absolutely fine if the order lines are less, say 4 - 10. This issue happens only when we test with 100 order lines on each of the order.

Comment: Why not simply wait a while, or lower the limit from 10 to maybe 5 orders?

Comment: Please note that no questions are urgent here - volunteers don't generally take well to being rushed.

Comment: Christoffer - Sorry but the same issue exists. When there is a huge number of order lines, even though I set it to just 3 orders in batch, first one works, second one skips and third one works.

Comment: @halfer But I just added it for may be someone who might think they shall answer later. Thanks for the information, btw!